# Is this equal, getApplication() and initializing instance with regular "new"?

Tags: java, android

I have

- `FirstClass`, extends `android.app.Activity`
- `SecondClass`, extends `android.app.Application`

`SettingsSaver settings` is located in `FirstClass`;

So, is this equal:

- `SettingsSaver settings = ( (SecondClass) getApplication() ).getSettings();`
- `SettingsSaver settings = new SecondClass().getSettings();`

If so, what is difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first one, don't new the Application class yourself. You want to get the instance of Application that is initialised by the system.